# How to find out if there is at least one key in a hash

Tags: perl

There is such a hash:

```
$hash = { Apple => 'red', Lemon => 'yellow', Carrot => 'orange' }
```

How do you know if there is at least one key in the hash?

Comment: `if(keys %{$hash})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decide the hash key size using: `scalar keys(%hash)`. Based on the size your check can be done below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = ( 
    Apple  => 'red', 
    Lemon  => 'yellow', 
    Carrot => 'orange'
);

print Dumper(\%hash);

print "Size:".scalar keys(%hash)."\n";

if(scalar keys(%hash) > 0){
    print "Hash size is greater than 1\n";
} else {
    print "Hash size is zero\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply using the hash in scalar context will suffice.

```perl
if (%hash) {         # Or %$hash in your case.
   say "Not empty";
} else {
   say "Empty";
}
```

---

**`%hash` vs `keys(%hash)`**

- `keys(%hash)` in scalar context: Returns the number of elements.
- `%hash` in scalar context (≥5.26): Returns the number of elements.
- `%hash` in scalar context (<5.26): Returns whether the hash is empty or not.

So, no matter the version, you can always simply use `%hash` in scalar context to check if a hash is empty. `keys(%hash)` can be used to achieve the same result, but `%hash` in boolean context (e.g. `if (%hash)`) has been faster than an equivalent use of `keys(%hash)` since 5.12.

So, no matter the version, you can always simply use `keys(%hash)` in scalar context to get the number of elements in the hash. You can also use `%hash` in scalar context in newer versions.

Comment: (I was composing this when Сухой27 posted their similar answer.)

Comment: (It took me a while to compose cause I was trying to find out when `%hash` in boolean context was optimized. I failed then, but I have since figured it out. Updated answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Hash returns non-false value in scalar context when populated, or key - value pairs in list context.

You can simply check if it is not empty with,

```
if (%$hash)...
```

Answer (score 1):

Above mentioned methods are good.  But if you want more information about hash you can use https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Util module.

bucket_info method : Return a set of basic information about a hash.

- 0: Number of keys in the hash
- 1: Number of buckets in the hash
- 2:    Number of used buckets in the hash
- rest : list of counts, Kth element    is the number of buckets
  with K keys in it.

> Code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Hash::Util qw(bucket_info);

my $hash = { Apple => 'red', Lemon => 'yellow', Carrot => 'orange' };
my $empty_hash = {};

my ($keys, $buckets, $used, @length_counts)= bucket_info($hash);

print "\n Number of keys $keys in the hash \n";
print "\n Number of buckets $buckets in the hash \n";
print "\n Number of used buckets $used in the hash \n";

((bucket_info($hash))[0]) ? print "\n Not Empty hash" : print "\n Empty hash";

((bucket_info($empty_hash))[0]) ? print "\n Not Empty hash" : print "\n Empty hash";
```

> output

```
Number of keys 3 in the hash

 Number of buckets 8 in the hash

 Number of used buckets 2 in the hash

 Not Empty hash
 Empty hash
```